# Is it a sin to break an unfair oath?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

Let's say someone was forced into making an oath on the Quran to vote for the incumbent government upon becoming a citizen of that country. The person could not become a citizen without making this oath, so they're coerced into doing so. However, the person might not think that it's fair to vote for the government and the oath itself is legally dishonest.

So, what kind of sin would happen to a person who keeps to that oath? Is it fine for them to break it or must they keep it?

Comment: Is this kind of citizenship a real world example from any country?

Comment: Can't actually verify. There are rumors, but nobody really knows the right thing to do if put in such a situation.

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: Would rather not say. If the rumor is not true, then it would be slander. Let's just take it as a hypothetical example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking a swear you made in Allah's name](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/breaking-a-swear-you-made-in-allahs-name)

Comment: @Muz first of Oaths on Quran are not valid and is Shirk,[A Vow to Another Besides Allah (Subhanahu wa-ta'ala) is Shirk](http://abdurrahman.org/tawheed/KTwahab/beliefs/creed/abdulwahab/KT1-chap-10.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very clear verse in Quran regarding this and its expiation.

> لَا يُؤَاخِذُكُمُ اللَّهُ بِاللَّغْوِ فِي أَيْمَانِكُمْ وَلَٰكِن يُؤَاخِذُكُم بِمَا عَقَّدتُّمُ الْأَيْمَانَ ۖ فَكَفَّارَتُهُ إِطْعَامُ عَشَرَةِ مَسَاكِينَ مِنْ أَوْسَطِ مَا تُطْعِمُونَ أَهْلِيكُمْ أَوْ كِسْوَتُهُمْ أَوْ تَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ ۖ فَمَن لَّمْ يَجِدْ فَصِيَامُ ثَلَاثَةِ أَيَّامٍ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ كَفَّارَةُ أَيْمَانِكُمْ إِذَا حَلَفْتُمْ ۚ وَاحْفَظُوا أَيْمَانَكُمْ ۚ كَذَٰلِكَ يُبَيِّنُ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ آيَاتِهِ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَشْكُرُونَ
>   Sahih International
>   Allah will not impose blame upon you for what is meaningless in your oaths, but He will impose blame upon you for [breaking] what you intended of oaths. So its expiation is the feeding of ten needy people from the average of that which you feed your [own] families or clothing them or the freeing of a slave. But whoever cannot find [or afford it] - then a fast of three days [is required]. That is the expiation for oaths when you have sworn. But guard your oaths. Thus does Allah make clear to you His verses that you may be grateful.
>   5:89

As well as this

> لَّا يُؤَاخِذُكُمُ اللَّهُ بِاللَّغْوِ فِي أَيْمَانِكُمْ وَلَٰكِن يُؤَاخِذُكُم بِمَا كَسَبَتْ قُلُوبُكُمْ ۗ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ حَلِيمٌ
>   Sahih International
>   Allah does not impose blame upon you for what is unintentional in your oaths, but He imposes blame upon you for what your hearts have earned. And Allah is Forgiving and Forbearing.
>   2:225

Allah is the ever Forgiving and the most Merciful.

Answer (score 1):

A Muslim should only swear by Allah Ta'ala as the words of the Prophet:

> "Those who swear, swear by Allah or remain silent"

Holding the Mushaf (Quran) during the swearing is not one of the requirements oath. But it does not matter if he swore during, his hands holding the Qur'an, because Qur'an is ***Kalaamullah***  and he is one of God's nature. This scenario can be seen in a matter involving the court is not Islam that requires a person to use swears scripture.

In the Qur'an surah Al-Maidah: 89

> "You are not mistaken for one by Allah about the vows you are not
>   deliberate (to swear), but you thought wrong by him with an oath that
>   deliberately because you made with earnest ..."

So, swearing as a citizenship provision allowed by Islam even if not in line with our principles because it is not our desire to swear .. hopefully we are always in forgiveness of Allah Ta'ala .. Aamiin

Allah knows best